# Deleting node from BST fails with empty result -- yet my code is based on working solution code

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I am trying to solve GeeksforGeeks problem [Delete a node from BST](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/delete-a-node-from-bst/1)
:

> Given a Binary Search Tree and a node value X. Delete the node with the given value X from the BST. If no node with value x exists, then do not make any change.
>
> #### Example 1:
>
> ```
> Input:
>       2
>     /   \
>    1     3
> X = 12
> ```
>
> **Output:** 1 2 3
>
> **Explanation:** In the given input there
> is no node with value 12 , so the tree
> will remain same.
>
> #### Your Task:
>
> You don't need to read input or print anything. Your task is to complete the function `deleteNode()` which takes two arguments. The first being the `root` of the tree, and an integer `X` denoting the node value to be deleted from the BST. Return the root of the BST after deleting the node with value X. Do not make any update if there's no node with value X present in the BST.

After seeing the solution I tried to code the solution myself.

Here is my attempt:

```
def getSuccessor(node):
    node = node.right
    while node and node.left:
        node = node.left
    return node.data
#Function to delete a node from BST.
def deleteNode(root, X):
    # code here.
    if root is None:
        return root
    elif root.data>X:
        root.left = deleteNode(root.left,X)
    elif root.data<X:
        root.right = deleteNode(root.right,X)
    else:
        if root.left is None:
            return root.right
        elif root.right is None:
            return root.left
        else:
            root.data = getSuccessor(root)
            # print(root.data)
            root.right = deleteNode(root.right,root.data)
        return root
```

This is the working solution I had looked up before trying myself:

```
#User function Template for python3

def getSuccessor(node):
    node = node.right
    while node and node.left:
        node = node.left
    return node 

def deleteNode(root, X):
    if root is None:
        return root
    elif root.data > X:
        root.left = deleteNode(root.left, X)
    elif root.data < X:
        root.right = deleteNode(root.right, X)
    else:
        if root.left is None:
            return root.right
        elif root.right is None:
            return root.left
        else:
            temp = getSuccessor(root)
            root.data = temp.data  
            root.right = deleteNode(root.right, temp.data)  
    return root
```

I have only changed `getSuccessor` function above as I only need the `node.data`. But it's not working. I think it has to do with Python passing the object by reference, but I can't understand how?

I tried changing the solution, but I can't make it to work. For the very first test case (see above), it outputs nothing, while the tree 1 2 3 is expected.

Comment: Obligatory: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/986006/11082165), [what does it mean by 'passed by assignment'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50534394/11082165)

Comment: Hi @Brian61354270 I read these articles but I am still unable to figure out the answer.

Comment: This has nothing to do with pass by reference. I updated your question to  focus on the problem, have the code challenge quoted, and specify what exactly is the unexpected output of your failing code.

Answer (score 0):

> I have only changed `getSuccessor` function above

There are more differences. You have moved the final `return root`, and by consequence there are now scenarios where your function doesn't execute a `return` statement, returning `None`.

This should have been easy to spot. The fix is to place the `return root` statement exactly where it was in the working version, i.e. with the same indentation.