# How to delete an object in python

Tags: python, object, oop

I have a simple code

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,val = 0):
        self.val = val
        self.right = None
       
def func(obj,n):
    if not n:
        obj = None
        return
    
    obj.right = Node()
    func(obj.right,0)
    
root = Node()
func(root,1)

#print(root.right.val)
#this gives me 0. How?? it should give me error
```

When I run this code, I notice that obj=None does nothing and my initial object which is root in the above program still has root.right component and its value is 0. Can anyone please explain whats going on and how do i fix the issue?
The desired behaviour that I want is, root.val should be 0 and root.right should be None. Thank you.

Comment: At no point is `root.right.val` "deleted" so why should it error? You need to read about how Python handles variables. `obj = None` does nothing more than pointing the variable `obj` to  `None`, it does nothing to what `obj` was pointing to before that.

Comment: you cannot delete python objects.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga by delete, I believe they mean to reassign the variable to `None`.

Comment: In *func()*, *obj* is a reference to a Node object. When you assign None to *obj* you do not affect the underlying object. You're merely changing the value of *obj*

Comment: I see you try to assign obj = None within the func function, it only affects the local variable obj within the function. It doesn't affect the original object root outside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, function arguments are [passed by assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50534394/what-does-it-mean-by-passed-by-assignment). Your code looks somewhat similar to the following:

```
root = Node()
obj = root
obj = None
```

As you can see, the variable `root` in the outer scope is not reassigned to a new value. And because it the old value is still referenced, it will not be cleaned by garbage collection.

An easy solution here, would be to `return` the new value which should take place of root. That way you can allow the result of the function to be used to reassign the passed in variable from the outer scope. e.g.

```
def func(obj,n):
    if not n:
        return None
    
    obj.right = func(Node(), 0)
    return obj

root = Node()
root = func(root,1)
```