# Modifying a copy of an object is modifying the original object simultaneously

Tags: flutter, dart

When changing a `DateTime` property of a copy of an object, it is also updating the original object. In the below code, when the button is pressed, I expect only the `_reminder.dueDate` to be updated, but both `_reminder.dueDate` and `widget.reminder.dueDate` are being updated at the same time.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:realminder/models/reminder.dart';

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  final Reminder reminder; // <-- Original object

  Test({
    @required this.reminder,
  });

  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  Reminder _reminder;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _reminder = widget.reminder; // <-- Create a copy of object

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        _reminder.dueDate = DateTime.now(); // <-- Both objects being updated here... Why?
      },
    );
  }
}
```

*Before `_reminder.dueDate = DateTime.now();`:*
[image]

*After `_reminder.dueDate = DateTime.now();`:*
[image]

Comment: [see this on passing by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25170094/what-is-the-true-meaning-of-pass-by-reference-in-modern-languages-like-dart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by making an actual copy of the object since I learned _reminder = widget.reminder is still referencing the same object.

In my reminder object, I made a copy feature which returned a new reminder with the same properties as the original.

*Reminder object:*

```dart
  Reminder clone() {
    return Reminder(
      dueDate: this.dueDate,
    );
  }
```

*Widget:*

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    _reminder = widget.reminder.clone();

    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: I am trying the same solution, but it is not working for me. Could you please help me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73208409/making-changes-in-cloned-object-instance-reflects-everywhere-the-object-is-being

Comment: This is my query, same issue. Kindly help me with this problem. It would be highly appreciable.