# Making changes in Cloned Object instance reflects everywhere the object is being passed as parameter Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am passing a cloned object instance as parameter to anther widget. But issue I am facing is that if any changes occur in the object the cloned object which was passed previously also reflects changes.
This is model class:

```html
class Food {
  String id;
  String name;
  double price; 
  double singleItemPrice;
  String image;

  Food clone() => Food(
        id,
       name,
        price,
        singleItemPrice,
        image,   
      );

  Food(
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.price,
    this.singleItemPrice,
    this.image,
   
  );

}
```

This is code where object is passed as param to another widget, where it is added to cart. `HotKeysWidget.of(context)! .updateCartList(dealItem, 1, false, [], items);` function is called to add item to cart. I am calling this function on clicking of Done button.

```html
Future specialDealDialog() {
    return showGeneralDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      barrierLabel: MaterialLocalizations.of(context).modalBarrierDismissLabel,
      barrierColor: Colors.black45,
      transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      pageBuilder: (BuildContext buildContext, Animation animation,
          Animation secondaryAnimation) {
        return Dialog(
          child: SpecialDealsWidget(
            deal: item.clone(),
            setSelection: (dealItem, items, changesMade) {
              print('DEAL TOTAL PRICE: ${dealItem.totalPrice}');

              HotKeysWidget.of(context)!
                  .updateCartList(dealItem, 1, false, [], items);
            },
            editDeal: false,
            closeDialog: (deal) {
              //resetDealData(deal.clone());
              //resetDealData(deal);
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

```html
class SpecialDealsWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  Food deal;
  Function(Food, List<Map<String, dynamic>>, bool) setSelection;
  bool editDeal;
  Function(Food) closeDialog;

  SpecialDealsWidget({
    required this.deal,
    required this.setSelection,
    required this.editDeal,
    required this.closeDialog,
  });

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return SpecialDealsWidgetState();
  }
}

class SpecialDealsWidgetState extends State<SpecialDealsWidget> {
  late Future<Food> data;
  Food? menuItem;
  final GlobalKey<DealItemWidgetState> modKey = GlobalKey();
  double totalPrice = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    menuItem = widget.deal.clone();
    if (!widget.editDeal) {
      data = fetchData();
    } else {
      totalPrice = menuItem!.totalPrice;
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<Food> fetchData() async {
    menuItem!.totalPrice = menuItem!.price;
    totalPrice = menuItem!.totalPrice;
    menuItem!.dealItem!.selectedItems = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < menuItem!.dealItem!.items.length; i++) {
      menuItem!.dealItem!.items[i].singleMenuPrice = 0.0;
      if (menuItem!.dealItem!.items[i].selected) {
        menuItem!.dealItem!.items[i].selected = false;
      }

      for (int j = 0; j < menuItem!.dealItem!.items[i].itemMenu.length; j++) {
        menuItem!.dealItem!.items[i].itemMenu[j].selectedItem = null;
      }

      /////////////LOOP THROUGH DROPDOWNS FOR SINGLE DEAL ITEM
      for (int f = 0; f < menuItem!.dealItem!.items[i].itemMenu.length; f++) {
        for (int j = 0;
            j < widget.deal.dealItem!.items[i].itemMenu[f].menuItemList.length;
            j++) {
          menuItem!.dealItem!.items[i].itemMenu[f].menuItemList[j]
              .selectedModifiers = [];
          menuItem!.dealItem!.items[i].itemMenu[f].menuItemList[j].extrasIDS =
              [];
          if (menuItem!
              .dealItem!.items[i].itemMenu[f].menuItemList[j].modifierExist) {
            for (int h = 0;
                h <
                    menuItem!.dealItem!.items[i].itemMenu[f].menuItemList[j]
                        .modifiers.length;
                h++) {
              menuItem!.dealItem!.items[i].itemMenu[f].menuItemList[j]
                  .modifiers[h].allFilled = false;
              menuItem!.dealItem!.items[i].itemMenu[f].menuItemList[j]
                  .modifiers[h].currentSelections = 0;
            }
          }
        }
      }

      ////////////RESET DEAL ITEM SELECTED ITEM
      if (menuItem!.dealItem!.items[i].selectedItem != null) {
        menuItem!.dealItem!.items[i].selectedItem = null;
        menuItem!.dealItem!.items[i].selectedCatIndex = null;
        menuItem!.dealItem!.items[i].selectionMade = false;
      }
    }
    return menuItem!;
  }

}
```

In above code snippet the issue occurs, When I open this dialog window and click Done button, item add to cart successfully. But when I reopen this window and close it without clicking Done button it alters the cart item.
The changes which are defined in the above `fetchData` method. I don't get it how it is changing the cart item. I am just opening and closing the window and doing nothing, no method on closing nothing

Anyone kindly help me with this issue. It's been quite long time I am facing this issue but has not yet found any solution. Although I am cloning the object instance which is apparently the solution in my search so far

Comment: Your clone method in Food class is returning the properties of the food "ins" when it should return a NEW one.

Comment: Later I removed that "ins" parameter and tried the above updated code snippet, but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
Food clone(){
    final<Food> clone = new Food(id,
                                 name,
                                 price,
                                 singleItemPrice,
                                 image,);
    return clone;
}
```

...untested and written while driving...sory for any error.

Comment: Greatly appreciate your time and effort in helping. But the issue still exist with this try.

Comment: Put "menuItem = widget.deal.clone();" ouside initState.

Comment: ```menuItem = widget.deal.clone();``` cannot be placed outside initState method. It gives errro.

Comment: Hello. Why are you clonning your food twice? One when SpecialDealsWidget is instantiated and other on its initState.

Comment: I thought cloning second time might help prevent changes reflect back, but none of it works. It's quite long I've been looking for this solution.

Comment: Instead of initState(), try didChangeDependencies().

Comment: Same result with ```didChangeDependencies()```

Comment: In your "Future specialDealDialog", where does "item" come from?

Comment: "item" comes from ```ListView``` widget,