# Assigning an object to another hold a reference of the assigned Object. Why is this if Dart is Assigned by Value

Tags: dart

I have a simple programme in dart to test out if variables assigned hold reference.

```
 class User{
  int? id;
  String? name;
  int? age;

  User(this.id, this.name, this.age);
}



  User user1 = User(1,'Harry', 21);
  User user2 = user1;
  user2.name =  'James';

  print(user1.name); //prints out James
  print(user2.name); //prints out James
```

I read that Dart is an Assigned by value language. So why does user1.name have a value of `James` and not `Harry` even if it was not explicitly changed?.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/25170094/

Answer (score 2):

Dart is an object oriented language, and like almost every other object oriented language, objects have identity.

That means objects are not denotable values, though; you can't store an object in a variable because the object has an existence, an identity, independent of that variable. You can only store a *reference* to an object in the variable.

Dart *is* call-by-value, but all the values are *object references*.

It's the same in Java, JavaScript and Python. C# has non-object values too, but for its objects, aka. "reference types", it works exactly the same. Dart does not have any values which are not objects.