# how to run a while loop in a function correctly

Tags: function, dart, while-loop

so, I'm collecting input and using a while loop with the condition (if user omits input say...) I am using this while loop for several input collection in the same code so i decided to write a function for it with a couple parameters, however after user skips input and later enters it, it doesn't register, output should print `"how are you $input"` however it just prints `"how are you"` and leaves input blank

```
main() {
  // First name
  print('First name:');
  var name1 = stdin.readLineSync();
  void conds(name, shitbe) {
    while (name.isEmpty) {
      print('Field cannot be empty');
      print(shitbe);
      name = stdin.readLineSync();
    }
  }

  conds(name1, 'First name:');

  print('How are you $name1');
```

output should be like

```
PS C:\tools\Projects> dart playground.dart
First name:

Field cannot be empty 
First name:
John    
How are you John 
PS C:\tools\Projects>
```

but this is what I'm getting after the first omission

```
PS C:\tools\Projects> dart test.dart      
First name:

Field cannot be empty
First name:
John
How are you 
PS C:\tools\Projects>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with a `while` loop.  It's about your function reassigning a parameter (a local variable) and expecting that assignment to affect the caller.  [Dart is pass-by-value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25170094/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All variables in Dart is references to objects. When you give a variable as argument to a method, the variable is copied so we got a copy of this reference.

Inside the method, you can do whatever you want with this reference but if you change what object the reference/variable points to, this change will not be seen by the code calling your method.

So inside `conds()` you are changing `name`, which is an argument, to point to a new `String` object you got from the user. But the caller of `conds()` will not see the change of the `name1` variable since the reference got copied into the method.

I would personally rewrite the code to something like this where the method handles all the interaction with the user and returns the `String` afterwards.

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  // First name
  final name = getInput('First name:');
  print('How are you $name');
}

String getInput(String message) {
  print(message);
  var input = stdin.readLineSync();

  while (input == null || input.isEmpty) {
    print('Field cannot be empty');
    print(message);
    input = stdin.readLineSync();
  }

  return input;
}
```

Comment: omdssssss ^^ Thanksssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss a lotttttt, taken the advice to account as well, i didn't realise it copied the references and worked with them as such