# Not getting the expected parameter with Navigator.push

Tags: flutter, dart

I am having a very odd problem. `record: data` is being passed correctly; different for every record as expected. But not `colorIndex`. It's always `8`, which is the number of the last item on my list. What's wrong?

**List Widget**

```
class NameList extends StatelessWidget {
  const NameList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int colorIndex = 0;

    return Container(
      child: GridView.count(
        primary: false,
        children: names.map((data) {
          colorIndex < Colors.primaries.length - 1
              ? colorIndex++
              : colorIndex = 0;

          return Ink(
            color: Colors.primaries[colorIndex][100],
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => DetailPage(
                      record: data,
                      colorIndex: colorIndex,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: Hero(
                tag: data.id,
                child: Text(
                  'OK',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Details**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './models.dart';

class DetailPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Name record;
  final int colorIndex;

  const DetailPage({Key? key, required this.record, required this.colorIndex})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Name: " + record.name);
    print("Color: " + colorIndex.toString());

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(
            'Test',
          ),
        ),
        body: Hero(
          tag: record.id,
          child: Container(
            height: 300,
            color: Colors.primaries[colorIndex][100],
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                record.name,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are incrementing `colorIndex` inside map, and it becomes the last number of the last item on my list after the build, because it is passing reference of `colorIndex` variable.

To solve this, you can create another variable from loop state inside map and use it on `DetailPage`.

```dart
children: names.map((data) {
      colorIndex < Colors.primaries.length - 1
          ? colorIndex++
          : colorIndex = 0;
      final c = colorIndex; // it will get separate value on each (map)iteration
......

 DetailPage( colorIndex: c, ..)
```

You can check

- [What is the true meaning of pass-by-reference in modern languages like Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25170094/10157127)

Comment: glad to help you out, you can follow attached link for more details.