# How to pass a function by reference in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way to call a function by reference not by values in flutter.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you exactly mean? what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you mean to ask is if it's possible to call a function and pass arguments by reference instead of by value, then not exactly.  Technically, Dart always uses pass-by-value ([although I prefer calling it "pass-by-assignment"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61281531/)).

If you want to simulate pass-by-reference, you could *wrap* your arguments in other objects to add a level of indirection:

```dart
class Reference<T> {
  T value;

  Reference(this.value);
}

void trimString(Reference<String> string) {
  string.value = string.value.trim();
}
```

Comment: Thanks jamesdlin this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In flutter Function is also first class object so you can pass them around any where.

you do it like

```
typedef ProfileFormSubmitCallback = void Function(
  String? photoUrl,
  String firstName,
  String lastName,
  String email,
);
then
```

you can reference your function like,

```
ProfileFormSubmitCallback myFunction;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how a function is passed and used. Hope this is what you want

```
class ButtonPrimary extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final double? height;
  final double? width;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;
 

  const ButtonPrimary({
    Key? key,
    required this.onPressed,
    required this.text,
    this.height,
    this.width,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: height ?? 50,
      width: width ?? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .6,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: onPressed,
        child: Widget(...),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And usage,

```
  ButtonPrimary(
   onPressed: onLoginPressed,
   text: 'Register',
   width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .9,
  )

  ....

  void onLoginPressed() {
    // Do sth
  }
```