# Flutter: Why can't remove an item from a list with the .remove() method and a textFormField

Tags: flutter, list, dart

Hi I have a list of Daytile objects and I want to remove them based on an AlertDialog that asks the user to input the name of the dayTile they want to remove. However, even when inputting the name exactly as it is, the element is never removed from the list.

Removal Logic

```
TextFormField(controller: titleController, inputFormatters: [
                LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(14),
              ]),
```

...

```
TextButton(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          setState(() {
                            dayTiles.remove(
                                DayTile(title: titleController.text));
                            // print(dayTiles);
                          });
                          saveData();
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                        child: const Text("Remove")),
```

Thank You!

Comment: can you share how's your model class look a like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating new instance, what do you need is to find item index on this case.

```dart
final itemIndex = dayTiles.indexWhere((element) => element.title == titleController.text);
  if(itemIndex>-1)
      dayTiles.removeAt(itemIndex));
```

Find more about [What is the true meaning of pass-by-reference in modern languages like Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25170094/10157127)